# Express route handler like functionality in Sails applications

Tags: node.js, sails.js

> **TL;DR** Is there a way to have Sails applications work similar to Express route handlers?

I'm working on an application that has a few major components (e.g. ecommerce, blogging and so on). It's working all fine, but the huge number of models, controllers and views is making it difficult for me to visualize them as separate components and making me feel a little too congested for comfort.

I've been through threads like [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/876) and I understand nesting is available for controllers, but I really want to split my project into discrete components.

What I'm doing now is splitting the project into different applications and exposing their REST APIs for the gluing application to show its magic. At least this would do the much-needed segregation. But how do I make the endpoints accessible to the gluing application? Using [req](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)? While that would give me the liberty to host the other components on another machine, it would slow things down considerably, right? Is there a way to interact with the other processes "directly", something like route handlers in Express (though they're not separate processes)? I would ideally like to have them running as separate processes so one component doesn't bring everything down on failure. At the same time, I want the interaction to be as "local" as possible.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Also, is this more of a [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) question?